# No results on echo

Tags: php, json, api, echo

I made this php code to get a result from an API but it does not work. I did some echos for the variables to check if they show up on screen but still nothing shown up. Any solution or idea why?

Thanks.

```
 <?php
    $item = $_GET['item'];
    $item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
    $item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
    $item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
    $item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
    @include_once ("pdocon.php");
    $code='SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1';
    echo $code;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($item));
    $rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(!empty($rs)) {
            if(time()-$rs["lastupdate"] < 604800) die($rs["cost"]);
    }
    $link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=(an api key here)&code=".$code"&names=".$item;
    $string = file_get_contents($link);
    $json = $string;

    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj;
    //print $obj->{"median_price"}; // 12345
    //$obj = json_decode($string);
    if($obj->{'status'} == "success") die("notfound");
    $lowest_price = $obj->{'price'};
    $lowest_price=str_replace("$", "", $lowest_price);
    $lowest_price = (float)($lowest_price);

    //$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM items WHERE name=?");
    //$stmt->execute(array($item));
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE items SET `cost` = ?,`lastupdate` = ? WHERE `name` = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($lowest_price, time(), $item));
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO items (`name`,`cost`,`lastupdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($item, $lowest_price, time()));
    echo $lowest_price;
    ?>
```

UPDATE: Results are not imported into the database for some reason, so I'll try to break everything into smaller parts:
This is the code from pdocon.php:

```
<?php
$user="";
$pass="";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testjackpot', $user, $pass);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

This is how the table auth looks like:
https://gyazo.com/75ea3a77773820f0c3adbdc24fc99185

This is the result of the API call:
https://gyazo.com/efe5680baad104be97281c5dac3d2c58

For some reason, even doing print_r($code) let's say, nothing is shown on the webpage generated from this php.

UPDATE2:

Tried to use

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
@include_once ("set.php");
$code=mysql_query("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1");
echo $code;
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name='$item'");
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    if(time()-$row["lastupdate"] < 3600) die($row["cost"]);
}
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=(code)&code=".$code."&names=".$item."&delimiter=!END!";
$string = file_get_contents($link);
echo $string;
$obj = json_decode($string);
if($obj->{'success'} == "0") die("notfound");
$lowest_price = $obj->data->prices[0]->price;
$lowest_price[strlen($lowest_price)] = 0;
$lowest_price = str_replace("$","",$lowest_price);
$lowest_price = (float)($lowest_price);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM items WHERE name='$item'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (`name`,`cost`,`lastupdate`) VALUES ('$item','$lowest_price','".time()."')");
echo $lowest_price;
?>
```

Still not showing anything.
UPDATE3: For the last code above I finally get something: gyazo. com/9fde818695abac2f4fe7997482ba5865

Comment: `json_decode` generates array, so add `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to check

Comment: If you didn't even get first echo, that's because the include_once is killing you. And remove that "@" off , for gods sake. Never use it! If you don't want warning to show up, tidy up your code

Comment: It still doesn't get the prices from the API..

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your syntax - there must be a dot between `$code` and `"&names`

```
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=(an api key here)&code=".$code."&names=".$item;
```

To see errors you made - you can add

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

to your .htaccess file (only at the developer version of the site)

Comment: @bogdanb So.. it should be there, isn't it ?

Comment: oh... I thought you said there shouldn't

Comment: @bogdanb you have to process the result you've got by mysql_query. For this you should use such functions as mysql_fetch_array, mysql_fetch_row etc. 2) You can't see the result of mysql_query by just using echo, because it's an object. Echo is mainly for integers, strings and so on.

Comment: That's why you're getting @Resource id #40.

Comment: So, you should Fetch the result from variable $code.

Comment: $code=mysql_fetch_array("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1"); ?

Comment: my bad: $code=mysql_query("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1"); $rx = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)?

Comment: So this should work                                                                                  $code=mysql_query("SELECT auth FROM auth where id=1");
$rx=mysql_fetch_array($code); echo $rx["auth"];
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name='$item'");
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
 if(time()-$row["lastupdate"] < 3600) die($row["cost"]);
}
$link = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=key&code=".$rx."&names=".$item."&delimiter=!END!";

Comment: I also have a bot outside that runs var itemname = wgg[i].market_name;
        var url = 'http://'+sitename+'/cost.php?item='+encodeURIComponent(itemname);
        (function(someshit) {
        request(url, function(error, response, body){  .................... cost.php is the file with the code in this thread.

Comment: Yes. It should. By the way, good practiсe is to search by id of an item. It's used if speed is important and it's possible to use ID field. But all depends.

Comment: But all depends on what you're developing.

Comment: I am trying to get the price and put it in the database that's all

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the @ before include_once. Maybe the path is wrong or the file not accessible.

Comment: not working. Prices are not generated (nothing in database table)